# Asserting exception message using FsUnit.Xunit

Tags: f#, xunit, fsunit

I'm trying to assert a certain exception type and message using FsUnit.Xunit.
There is some [`throwWithMessage`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsUnit/blob/master/src/FsUnit.Xunit/CustomMatchers.fs#L35) function that comes with FsUnit. However, when using it instead of the `throw` function fsc emits the following errors:

```
C:\src\foo.fs(29,12): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type '(unit -> unit) -> 'a' but here has type 'unit' 
C:\src\foo.fs(29,19): error FS0001: The type ''a -> NHamcrest.Core.CustomMatcher<obj>' is not compatible with the type 'NHamcrest.IMatcher<obj>' 
C:\src\foo.fs(29,12): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type '(unit -> unit) -> 'a' but here has type 'unit'
```

This is the test that won't compile:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Some test`` () =
    (fun () -> This.Throws("a", 10) |> ignore)
    |> should throwWithMessage "Some message" typeof<ArgumentException> //This is line 29
     //^ column index 12 is here
            //^ here is column index 19
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Versions:

- FsUnit/FsUnit.Xunit 3.1.0
- NHamcrest (as referenced by FsUnit.Xunit) 2.0.1
- Xunit 2.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welp, I missed some brackets. This works:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Some test`` () =
    (fun () -> This.Throws("a", 10) |> ignore)
    |> should (throwWithMessage "Some message") typeof<ArgumentException>
```